# Varnish 4.1 + Turpentine : Varnish admin socket timeout

Tags: configuration, nginx, varnish

I have been trying for ages getting varnish + turpentine to work proper...
But turpentine keeps saying

> Error determining Varnish version: Varnish admin socket timeout. Failed to load configurator

and

> Error determining Varnish version: Failed to read response code from Varnish. Failed to load configurator

I dont know whats wrong.

My Nginx config:

```
upstream backend {
  # Varnish port – kan også være 80
  server 127.0.0.1:8081;
}

upstream website{
  server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:8;
  server_name website.dk;

 return 301 https://www.website.dk$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen        0.0.0.0:443 ssl;
    server_name   website.dk;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/www_website_dk.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/www_webite_dk.key;
    include /etc/nginx/ssl_common.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/location_common.conf;
}

server {
    listen 8080;

    server_name website.dk
    include /etc/nginx/common.d/top_common.conf;

    root /var/www/www.website.dk/deployed/current;

    index index.php;

    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://website.dk";

    include /etc/nginx/common.d/locations.conf;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/common.d/fcgi_common.conf;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE base;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS on;
    }
}
```

My varnish.params:

```
RELOAD_VCL=1
VARNISH_VCL_CONF=/etc/varnish/default.vcl
VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=8081
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=6082
VARNISH_SECRET_FILE=/etc/varnish/secret
VARNISH_STORAGE="malloc,256M"
VARNISH_USER=varnish
VARNISH_GROUP=varnish
DAEMON_OPTS="-p thread_pool_min=5 -p thread_pool_max=500 -p thread_pool_timeout=300 -p feature=+esi_disable_xml_check,+esi_ignore_other_elements \ -p vsl_reclen=4084 \ -p vcc_allow_inline_c=on \ -p vcc_allow_inline_c=on \ -p 'cc_command=exec cc -fpic -shared -Wl,-x -o %o %s -lcrypto -lssl' \ -p workspace_client=128k \ -p shm_reclen=4084"
```

**Turpentine configuration (Varnish options):**
Varnish version: 4.1.x
Server list: 127.0.0.1:8081

**Turpentine configuration (Cache options):**
Backend host: 172.20.252.8
Backend port: 8080

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=6082`

Comment: What should it be instead? and shouldnt this only affect the admin part? i guess it should still listen and catch in frontend, shouldnt it?

Comment: @BrittanyMoore Did you find any solution?